# Changing from int to int32 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I am doing an exercise from SPOJ, and it's a simple calculator. Everytime I try to submit an answer I get an NZEC error, and I wonder if it's because it should be defined as int32.
Here's my code:

```
import sys
n = input()
n = int(n)


i = 0
while n > i:
    znak, num1, num2 = input().split()
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)
    if znak == "+":
        b = num1 + num2
        print(b)
    elif znak == "-":
        b = num1 - num2
        print(b)
    elif znak == "*":
        b = num1 * num2
        print(b)
    elif znak == "/":
        b = num1 / num2
        print(b)
    elif znak == "%":
        b = num1 % num2
        print(b)
    i += 1

sys.exit(0)
```

I've tried a some "solutions" for this NZEC error, but nothing worked.

Comment: There's no need to use `sys.exit`, the program exits automatically.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure if it works properly for their compilator.

Comment: What makes you think you need to switch to `int32` (which doesn't exist)?

Comment: I don't know what a NZEC error is, but an input of `/ 1 0` will definitely throw an exception

Comment: In direction it says that result should be in int32.

Comment: can you post the question with input and expected output?or even the  link?

Comment: There's link but it's in polish "Wejście" means Input, "Wyjście" means otuput [link](http://pl.spoj.com/problems/CALC/)

Comment: @Jessus check my solution it should work for your testcases. its the complete program also you do not have to worry about int32 in python because you do not have to define integers using  `int` or `long` or `short` in python

Comment: Given this is Python 3, using `/` as your division operator would be wrong if the output should be truncated to integer. Use `//` for `int` (floor) division, `/` will get your `float` (true) division.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the result should be an integer, you should use `operator.floordiv`, i.e. `a // b`, not `a / b` <sup>1</sup>:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, floordiv, mod

op = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': floordiv, '%': mod}

for i in range(int(input())):
    znak, *nums = input().split()

    print(op[znak](*map(int, nums)))
```

By the way, the code above does *exactly* the same as yours, but it's around two times shorter!

How?

- why check if `znak` is equal to something with tons of `if/else` statements, if you could put all the math operators in a dictionary `op`, and get the operator you need with `op[znak]`?
- you're on Python 3, so you can use that nice `a, *b = iterable` syntax which extracts the first item of `iterable` into `a` and puts other items into a *list* `b`, which looks super nice
- each `op[znak]` is a function that accepts two arguments, so you convert `nums` to integers with `map(int, nums)` and then pass them as *separate arguments* with the asterisk: `*map(int, nums)`
- last, but not least, why use this C-style `while` loop index incrementing if there's the Pythonic way to do it - with `range(start, stop, [step])`?
- finally, you don't really need the variable `n`, so you can plug it into `range` right away

---

Pssst, dude, feeling in need of some craziness? Take a look at how you can squeeze all this into two lines:

```
from operator import*

sum(0for _ in map(print,((lambda znak,*nums:{'+':add,'-':sub,'*':mul,'/':floordiv,'%':mod}[znak](*map(int,nums)))(*input().split())for _ in range(int(input())))))
```

Or only *one line*:

```
sum(0for _ in map(print,((lambda znak,*nums:{'+':lambda a,b:a+b,'-':lambda a,b:a-b,'*':lambda a,b:a*b,'/':lambda a,b:a//b,'%':lambda a,b:a%b}[znak](*map(int,nums)))(*input().split())for _ in range(int(input())))))
```

These work exactly as the first version. Now, this is just for fun, to show how powerful Python is and how messy it can be. *Don't try this at home :D*

---

<sup>1</sup> True division vs Floor division: `1 / 10 == 0.1`, but `1 // 10 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution: The idea is to split input charter into tokens preserving their orders . in our case tokens are `operators` and `numbers` so it very simple using regular expressions. `[+-/*]` match any of those operators or any number of digits using `\d+`

```
n = input()
import re
while n>0:
    expression = input()
    operator,num1,num2 = re.findall('[+-/*]|\d+',expression)
    if operator == '+': print(int(num1) + int (num2))
    if operator == '-': print(int(num1) - int (num2))
    if operator == '*': print(int(num1) * int (num2))
    if operator == '%': print(int(num1) % int (num2))
    if operator == '/': print(int(num1) // int (num2))

    n = n - 1
```

Comment: Still, an integer divided by an integer like `a / b` will be a floating point number.

Comment: @ForceBru fixed

Comment: no, it's not: if you divide a number by a floating-point, you can be even more sure you'll get a floating-point as a result.

Comment: isn't that the requirement? i am  sorry if i missed that.

Comment: well, the OP said this in the comments: "In direction it says that result should be in int32."

Comment: if the input is int32 then how is it going to be floating point?

Comment: `1 / 10 == 0.1`.

Comment: @ForceBru no it will only be zero i checkd

Comment: you're using Python 2.x, but the OP is on Python 3.x